# how is calculated gcd of 4 number?

Tags: algorithm

does  `gcd(gcd(a,b),gcd(c,d))`  equal `gcd(a,b,c,d)`?or how can i calculate gcd of 4 number?

Comment: And what exactly does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes that is correct. If you are finding the gcd of (a,b,c,d) then any split should work. So gcd(a,b,c,d) = gcd(gcd (a,b) , gcd(c,d))

Answer (score 7):

Yes. GCD(a,b,c,d) = GCD(a, GCD(b, GCD(c, d))) (or any other order, its associative and commutative.) Oh, and just in case you didn't know, you can use the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute GCD very quickly.